# Getting error when easy_install'ing google-api-python-client under cygwin

Tags: installation, cygwin, easy-install, google-api-python-client

I am trying to install `google-api-python-client` on `cygwin` on a Windows 7 system. Following their [install instructions](https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client), I am trying to run

```
easy_install --upgrade google-api-python-client
```

But I am getting this error:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-12.1-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources /__init__.py:2512: PEP440Warning: 'bzr-fastimport (0.13.0.final.0)' is being parsed as a legacy, non PEP 440, version. You may find odd behavior and sort order. In particular it will be sorted as less than 0.0. It is recommend to migrate to PEP 440 compatible versions.
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-12.1-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py:2512: PEP440Warning: 'stgit (0.17.1-dirty)' is being parsed as a legacy, non PEP 440, version. You may find odd behavior and sort order. In particular it will be sorted as less than 0.0. It is recommend to migrate to PEP 440 compatible versions.
Searching for google-api-python-client
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/google-api-python-client/
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/google-api-python-client/: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:514: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed -- Some packages may not be found!
Couldn't find index page for 'google-api-python-client' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:514: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed -- Some packages may not be found!
No local packages or download links found for google-api-python-client
```

error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('google-api-python-client')

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

first install curl using apt-get

curl -O https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pip/pip-1.2.1.tar.gz

tar xvfz pip-1.2.1.tar.gz

cd pip-1.2.1

python setup.py install